# Amazon SP-API Fetching product

Tags: php, laravel, php-curl

How to fetch all the products associated with my seller account through the SP-api in amazon?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a look at this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to be able to [post a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Using the Amazon portal, generate a refresh token (`Atzr|....`). Note your client ID and client secret as well.
Pass it as a parameter to the following function:

```php
define('CLIENT_ID','amzn1.application-oa2-client.....');
define('CLIENT_SECRET','amzn1.oa2-cs.v1.....');

function writeLog($s,$level = 'INFO') {
    print($level . "\t" . $s . "\r\n");
}

function getToken($refresh_token) {
    try {
        $url = sprintf('https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=%s&client_id=%s&client_secret=%s',$refresh_token,CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array());
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $responseCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($responseCode > 300) {
            throw new Exception($result, $responseCode);
        }
        return json_decode($result)->access_token;
    } catch(Exception $ex) {
        writeLog($ex->getMessage(),'ERROR');
    }
}
$your_auth_token = getToken('Atzr|...');
```

Once you have the authorization token, use it to retrieve data from your desired endpoint, e.g.:

```php
function http_request(string $url, string $token, array $params = array()) {
    try {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json","User-Agent: YourSuperApp","x-amz-access-token: $token")); // Add the token to the header
        if (!empty($params)) { // this is a POST, add body. 
            //Some endpoints expect POST instead of GET, there you can pass the array of values as the 3rd parameter of this function
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($params));
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === false) {
            throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
        }
        return json_decode($result);
    } catch(Exception $ex) {
        writeLog($ex->getMessage(),'ERROR');
    }
}

$items = http_request('https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/catalog/2022-04-01/items?marketplaceIds=["A1PA6795UKMFR9"]',$your_auth_token);
```

Then you can process the JSON which should be in [this](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/catalog-items-api-v2022-04-01-reference#itemsearchresults) format. You might use `var_dump($items);` to see how it looks like.

Things to keep in mind:

1. API URLs are different per region, see [here](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/sp-api-endpoints). I used the EU one.
2. Marketplace IDs can be found [here](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/sp-api-endpoints). I used the german one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be doing serious work with SP API, I highly recommend you use a pre-built library. I'm a big fan of [selling-partner-api](https://github.com/jlevers/selling-partner-api) PHP library, which is Laravel compatible. I've been using it for years in multiple projects and it simplifies the process for getting the Amazon product catalog and many other SP API related functions.  Especially, if you're building a public app and need to deal with account authorizations, permissions, etc. I've been using it for creating and [processing FBA shipments](https://wizard-industries.com) without any issues.

Comment: https://github.com/jlevers/selling-partner-api doesn't support the latest SP API, The latest SP API doesn't have IAM. But this package requires IAM. Is there any solution?